# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'tuple' and 'dict'

Tags: django

I'm following this tutorial with a few changes: http://www.jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/, all of which I'll post as snippets below. When I attempt to access a page that goes through my dynamic form view it throws a TypeError. Here's the traceback: http://dpaste.com/793196/.

*forms.py (testing/forms.py)*

```
from django import forms

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    test_id = forms.CharField()
    user_id = forms.CharField()
    complete_time = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args **kwargs)

        for i, question in enumerate(extra):
            self.fields['custom_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label=question)
    def extra_answers(self):
        for name, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if name.startswith('custom_'):
                yield (self.fields[name].label, value)
```

*views.py (testing/views.py)*

```
def exam(request, test_id):
    user = request.user
    t = get_object_or_404(Test, pk=test_id)
    if user.is_authenticated():
        extra_questions = get_questions(request, test_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = TestForm(request.POST or None, extra=extra_questions)

            if form.is_valid():
                for (question, answer) in form.extra_answers():
                    save_answer(request, question, answer)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/tests/')
        else:
            form = TestForm(None, extra=extra_questions)

        return render(request, 'testing/exam.html', { 't' : t, 'form' : form })
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def get_questions(request, test_id):
    t = get_object_or_404(Test, pk=test_id)
    questions = t.question_set.all()
    for question in questions:
        title = question.question
        qlist = []
        qlist.append(title)
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm racking my mind for an answer.

Comment: Always show your error in full.

Comment: I pasted the entire traceback of the error. What else is there to show?

Comment: You are discouraged from using external paste sites, at least alone. If there's an insane amount, use dpaste, but always put the most material parts in your question.

Comment: Ah OK. So: 'Avoid external paste sites where possible'? That makes some sense.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You accidentally forgot the comma.

```
super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's crazy I was looking at my code for 30 minutes now like "I KNOW there's a missing comma somewhere" but I couldn't find it. Googled, read this answer, looked back at the code, found missing comma in less than 10 seconds.